# MS Access report does not fit to one page

Tags: ms-access, printing, report

How do you ensure that your MS Access created report fits to one page? I have multiple queries that the report references, but if i print preview i cannot get it all to fit to one page.

Comment: Do you mean that it's too **long** or too **wide** for one page? If it's too wide, you need to decrease the width. If it's too long...well, then you have too much data :-)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why, but this is what instantly popped into my head when I read this :-P

[image: meme]

but in seriousness ... you will probably need to do one of two things:

- If the size of your data is variable, you want to design the report so that it can optionally be on more than one page. don't try to force the data into a fixed format.
- If however the size/quantity of your data is fixed, you just need to keep tweaking. smaller fonts, less margin, etc. until it fits.

Comment: lol thats awesome and probably depicts how im feeling right about now! But basically its a bit of both...horizontal and vertical issues!

Comment: I know the feeling :-P I know the biz guys sometimes want things on a single page, but put on your UX hat for a second. there's only so much data you can fit onto a single page without making a user tear out their eyes. You may have to push back on the single page requirement if you've got too much data to display. good luck